# Jenkins to SCP a few folders and files from SVN to linux server?

Tags: linux, svn, tomcat, ant, jenkins

I use jenkins to do auto deployment weekly to a tomcat server, and it is fairly simple to do using the "curl" with the tomcat manager. and since i am only uploading a .war file, so its very straight forward.

But when comes to a backend console application, Anyone has any idea how to use jenkins to upload an entire "set of folders with files" onto a linux box? The project that i have is built via ant and has all the folder inside the SVN.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things come to mind.

Probably the most straightforward thing to do is use the ant `scp` task to push the directory / directories up to the server.  You'll need the jsch jar on your Ant classpath to make it work, but that's not too bad to deal with.  [See the Ant docs for the scp task here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html).  If you want to keep your main build script clean, just make another build script that Jenkins can run named 'deploy.xml' or similar.  This has the added benefit that you can use it from places other than Jenkins.

Another idea is to check them out directly on the server from SVN.  Again, ant can probably help you with this if you use the `sshexec` task, and run the subversion task inside of that.  [SSHexec docs here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html)

Finally, Jenkins has a "Publish Over SSH" plugin you might try out. I've not used it personally, but it looks promising!  [Right over here!](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)